# Saving image frames to a video

Tags: iphone, video, export, youtube, ios

Are there any easy solutions for saving a number of images into a video file in iOS?

Example: I have 300 frames all saved as separate images and want to turn them into a single video file (e.g., mp4) that a user could email or post on YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

No support in iOS, you may have to use open source libraries such as ffmpeg.